# How to use tokenColorCustomizations VS Code text color changer in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, color-scheme, textcolor

tokenColorCustomizations does not stick with **dart**, I can change JSON file but the color does not stick to it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart uses Semantic Tokens so you need to customise the semantic token colours rather than textmate tokens. For example:

```
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "rules": {
        "keyword.void": {
            "foreground": "#ffff99",
            "fontStyle": "underline"
        }
    }
},
```

This will make the void keyword (`keyword` is the type, `void` is a modifier) yellow and underlined:

[image: Void keyword yellow]

You can see which semantic token types/modifiers are applied to each item by using the **Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes** command in VS Code:

[image: Semantic token types and modifiers]

To change the colour of a class name, you could use:

```
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "rules": {
        "class": {
            "foreground": "#ff9999"
        }
    }
},
```

Which will look like this:

[image: Colour class names]

Comment: Hey Danny! Is it possible to customize the color of the "this" keyword?

Comment: @GroovinChip I don't think it's currently possible, but we do have some custom modifiers to allow things like that - it might be possible to add one for "this". Please file an issue.